# Timepicker Javascript displays time in incorrect way

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have a timepicker div tag in my HTML as : 
 `<input class="timepicker" name="timepicker" id="from-timepicker"/>`
The respective Javascript code is :

```
$('#from-timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            // year, month, day and seconds are not important
            minTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0),
            maxTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0),
            // time entries start being generated at 6AM but the plugin
            // shows only those within the [minTime, maxTime] interval
            startHour: 6,
            // the value of the first item in the dropdown, when the input
            // field is empty. This overrides the startHour and startMinute
            // options
            startTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 8, 20, 0),
            // items in the dropdown are separated by at interval minutes
            interval: 10
        });
```

On the UI, I see time as :

```
0808:mm
I need it in 08:08 (hh:mm) format.
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you try formatting as `timeFormat: 'hh:mm'` ?

Comment: have you tried using `'timeFormat': 'h:i'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out all :) 
Well of the two options, 'timeFormat': 'h:i' did the work fo me. 
@renmark Do you mind adding it as an answer so that I can mark an answered. ALao can you please explain how this worked out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

timepicker format: `'timeFormat': 'h:i'`

timepicker.jquery uses the time portion of [php.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: @OP, if you have accepted the answer, chances are you also want to upvote it.  :)  Helps bring quality to the top.

Comment: @renmark : Right now it is showing time in 12-hour format.
How do I change it to 24-hour format (without using AM/PM)?

Comment: @nerd.post sorry i've been busy these past few days, u can use big letter `H` for 24-hour format e.g. `'timeFormat': 'H:i'`

Comment: Yes Renmark, I got that working :) 
as commented above. Thank you.